# How to integrate angular2 inside laravel 5.4 without creating Laravel REST API

Tags: angular, laravel-5

I'm developing a system using laravel and I would like to create front end components (No need to handle all front end). But most of the tutorials advise to separate Angular and Laravel. I would like to use Angular inside Laravel. Anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The Scotch team has some good walkthroughs on getting up and running with Angular/Blade.

https://scotch.io/tutorials/quick-tip-using-laravel-blade-with-angularjs

Side note, Laravel 5.4 now includes a mechanic for natively using both Angular syntax and Blade syntax in the same view (essentially, prepend Angular tags with the `@` symbol):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#displaying-data

Comment: I tried it, but this is not actually what i want. I mean I want to know how combine those two frameworks together

Comment: Sorry, making your question more clear as to what specifically you are trying to achieve would help.

Comment: You just use Angular like you normally would, just do it from w/in the blade template files. You can pass Angular values from Blade and can make calls to your app's API if necessary.

Comment: I'm newbie to angular. So actually I want to know is there any trouble put angular in laravel root. Specially when scaling the project. I confuse on this because many tutors advice to put angular and laravel separately and consume Laravel resources using angular frontend. idea about this?